# CSS to create a div that takes remaining width of parent when the other sibling div is as wide as it's content?

Tags: html, css

How do I go about creating the next layout :

Two divs share the width of a common parent. both of them display text content in a single line, while -

- The div on the right is as wide as it's text content
- The div on the left takes up all the remaining width of the parent and uses text-overflow: ellipsis to display '...' where the text gets cut.

Here is what I think I know about how it should be implemented -

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: none;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'> This div should display all text content possible without line-breaking and display '...' where its being cut </div>
  <div class='right'> This div is as wide as its text content </div>
</div>
```

It should look like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZoXD.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Flexbox for this, just set `display: flex` on parent and `flex-shrink: 0` on right element.

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}
.right {
  background: lightblue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'> This div should display all text content possible without line-breaking and display '...' where its being cut </div>
  <div class='right'> This div is as wide as its text content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be you should remove flex-shrink, because as length of content increase in .right it works much similar to white-space:nowrap instead of breaking them to next line.

Comment: @frnt I agree with you, it's better to go with `flex:1` in my opinion.

Comment: It worked perfectly. all I needed to add was `flex:1` on the left component so that it will fill the remaining space in case the content of both divs is not enough to fill the parent's width.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better using **`Flexbox`** for this. You should give `display: flex;` to `.parent` and `flex:1;` to `.left`. That will do your trick and it will not over flow the **parent** width also.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: pink;
  flex:1;
}
.right {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'> This div should display all text content possible without line-breaking and display '...' where its being cut </div>
  <div class='right'> This div is as wide as its text content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.parent { 
   width: 300px; 
   height: 200px; 
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
}
.left {   
   white-space: nowrap; 
   text-overflow: ellipsis;  
   overflow: hidden;
  
 }
.right {
   white-space: nowrap; 
   text-overflow: ellipsis;  
   overflow: hidden;
 
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'> This div should display all text content possible without line-breaking and display '...' where its being cut </div>
  <div class='right'> This div is as wide as its text content </div>
</div>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` for your requirement. It is really simple and it will work like any other `display` properties. You can check this  [codepen link](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/LjOqxX). This works 100%.

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
.one, 
.two {
  flex-grow: 1;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.one {
  background-color: red;
}
.two {
  background-color: blue;
}
```